# PHP - command line arguments in Windows

Tags: php, command-line, parameters

I'm trying to run PHP from the command line under [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP).

That works, except for the fact that I am not able to provide parameters to my PHP script.

My test case:

```
echo "param = " . $param . "\n";
var_dump($argv);
```

I want to call this as:

```
php.exe -f test.php -- param=test
```

But I never get the script to accept my parameter.

The result I get from the above script:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: param in C:\test.php on line 2

```
param = ''
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(8) "test.php"
  [1]=> string(10) "param=test"
}
```

I am trying this using PHP 5.2.6. Is this a bug in PHP 5?

The parameter passing is handled in the [online help](https://www.php.net/features.commandline):

> Note: If you need to pass arguments to your scripts you need to pass -- as the first argument when using the -f switch.

This seemed to be working under PHP 4, but not under PHP 5.

Under PHP 4 I could use the same script that could run on the server without alteration on the command line. This is handy for local debugging, for example, saving the output in a file, to be studied.

Answer (score 7):

Why do you have any expectation that *param* will be set to the value?

You're responsible for parsing the command line in the fashion you desire, from the *$argv* array.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [getopt()](https://www.php.net/getopt) function.

Check blog post *[PHP CLI script and Command line arguments](http://sharingphp.blogspot.com/2011/04/php-cli-script-and-command-line.html)*.

Comment: According to this site: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/21/2/4 `getopt()` doesn't work in Windows (which the OP is using).

Answer (score 3):

> The parameter passing is handled in the online help Note: If you need to pass arguments to your scripts you need to pass -- as the first argument when using the -f switch. This seemed to be working under PHP 4, but not under PHP 5.

But PHP still doesn't parse those arguments.  It just passes them to the script in the *$argv* array.

The only reason for the **--** is so that PHP can tell which arguments are meant for the PHP executable and which arguments are meant for your script.

That lets you do things like this:

```
php -e -n -f myScript.php -- -f -n -e
```

(The -f, -n, and -e options **after** the `--` are passed to file *myScript.php*. The ones before are passed to PHP itself).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass the parameters similar to GET variables, then you can use the [parse_str()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function. Something similar to this:

```
<?php
    parse_str($argv[1]);
?>
```

Would produce a variable, *$test*, with a value of <myValue>.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not parameterize your command line parameters for you. See the output where your second entry in `ARGV` is "param=test".

You most likely want to use the PEAR package [Console_CommandLine](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_CommandLine): "A full featured command line options and arguments parser".

Or you can be masochistic and add code to go through your `ARGV` and set the parameters yourself. Here's a very simplistic snippet to get you started (this won't work if the first part isn't a valid variable name or there is more than 1 '=' in an `ARGV` part:

```
foreach($argv as $v) {
    if(false !== strpos($v, '=')) {
        $parts = explode('=', $v);
        ${$parts[0]} = $parts[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Command-line example:

```
    php myserver.php host=192.168.1.4 port=9000
```

In file *myserver.php*, use the following lines:

```
<?php
    parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
    // Read arguments

    if (array_key_exists('host', $_GET))
    {
        $host = $_GET['host'];
    }

    if (array_key_exists('port', $_GET))
    {
        $port = $_GET['port'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the first line `parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);` does exactly what is needed - to convert all they key=value pairs into a $_GET[ key => value ] array

Answer (score 0):

$argv is an array containing all your commandline parameters... You need to parse that array and set $param yourself.

```
$tmp = $argv[1];             // $tmp="param=test"
$tmp = explode("=", $tmp);   // $tmp=Array( 0 => param, 1 => test)

$param = $tmp[1];            // $param = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
if($argc > 1){
    if($argv[1] == 'param=test'){
        $param = 'test';
    }
}
```

Of course, you can get much more complicated than that as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
if (isset($argv[1]) {
  $arg1 = $argv[1];
  $arg1 = explode("=", $arg1);
  $param = $arg1[1];
}
```

(How to handle the lack of parameters is up to you.)

Or if you need a more complex scenario, look into a command-line parser library, such as the one from [Pear](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_CommandLine).

Using the `${$parts[0]} = $parts[1];` posted in another solution lets you override any variable in your code, which **doesn’t really sound safe**.

Answer (score 0):

If you like living on the cutting edge, PHP 5.3  has the [getOpt()](http://php.net/getopt) command which will take care of all this messy business for you. Somewhat.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the $argv array. Like this:

```
<?php
    echo $argv[1];
?>
```

Remember that the first member of the *$argv* array (which is *$argv[0]*) is the name of the script itself, so in order to use the parameters for the application, you should start using members of the *$argv[]* from the '1'th index.

When calling the application, use this syntax:

```
php myscript.php -- myValue
```

There isn't any need to put a name for the parameter. As you saw, what you called the *var_dump()* on the *$argv[]*, the second member (which is the first parameter) was the string *PARAM=TEST*. Right? So there isn't any need to put a name for the param. Just enter the *param* value.

Comment: `print_r($argv)` is more useful for troubleshooting an array, imho.